# what does fs.readFile send to its callback?

Tags: node.js, file-io

In a nodejs server suppose I read a file like so:

```
fs.readFile('path/to/file','encoding',function(err,data){
  //send data
  res.end(data);
});
```

What type of object is `data`, i.e is it a string, an array or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback):

> The callback is passed two arguments (err, data), where data is the contents of the file.
>
> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

The raw buffer is a byte array. You can convert it to a javascript string by calling `data.toString()`. For more conversion options, see [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).

Answer (score 1):

Without any options set,

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.